# Tile windows vertically with one click in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, tiles

I have multiple monitors and like to tile some emails vertically in the right half of one of the screens.

I use Dual Monitor Tools to place the emails in the right half of this screen, but they take up the half-screen from top to bottom.

I learned from a superuser post to highlight one of the emails and hit win-down arrow and it will vertically tile the emails, but to a maximum of 3 emails.  Great.  But it would be great if it could vertically tile more than 3 at a time.

The screen is big, so there is plenty of vertical room.

Does anybody know how to expand the limit of vertical tiles which can be created by using win-down arrow?

Trying to accomplish this through the taskbar doesn't seem to work for this purpose because it will try to tile the Outlook list of email messages which I don't want to include in the tiling, ie, I would like to leave the Outlook list of email messages where it is and only tile some emails themselves, yet the taskbar considers the list and the messages as part of one taskbar group.

Thanks in advance.